# Java adds spaces when reading in a line?

Tags: java

So I'm at my wit's end with this program. I'm reading in from a text file in Java. Barring everything that I do with the string once I have it, this is the bare minimum code to be shown.

```
            while ((lineIn = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("LineIn: \""+lineIn+"\"");
                System.out.println("Length: "+lineIn.length());
            }
```

What it prints out, however, is very strange indeed. The line should read:

`001    2014/06/09 09:40:24 0.000`

But this is what I get:

`LineIn: "�2�6�1�8� �2�0�1�4�/�0�7�/�1�0� �2�3�:�1�5�:�0�3� �0�.�0�0�0�"
Length: 61`

On Stack Overflow it actually shows up fine. You may be able to copy and paste the "LineIn: etc" into your address bar and see there are little invisible spaces in the numbering. I have no idea why those are there, what they are, and where Java is getting them from. Opening the document it's sourced from in a simple text editor shows no such spacing, and copy+pasting from the text editor into the browser address bar has no superfluous spacing either. It's very peculiar and I hope someone can offer insight. I'm pulling out my hair here.

Comment: Just for you to know before I fix it : Java and Javascript are as different as moon and Earth.

Comment: How is yout file encoded ?

Comment: @Dici: Or as similar as car and carpet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/367273

Comment: Try using a Scanner instead.

Comment: are you using `Scanner`? Scanner is a far simpler and easier choice. `Scanner` will infer the file's encoding automatically based on the BOM at the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're reading UTF-16 data as if it had an 8-bit encoding.

If you [construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) a `java.io.InputStreamReader`, you can specify the input text [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) such as "UTF-16".

Comment: to be complete, you should provide a way for him to fix his encoding. Namely, using `Scanner` would infer the encoding automatically based on the BOM at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Good point, @SnakeDoc. One can use the charset "UTF-16" to force 16-bit decoding, and it'll read an optional byte-order mark to distinguish big vs. little endian. The doc for `java.util.Scanner` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String) says defaulting the charset uses "the underlying platform's default charset." It doesn't say it'll automatically pick from UTF-16 vs. UTF-8.

Comment: Ended up using this and it worked. Thanks :)

`InputStreamReader fileInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInStream, "UTF-16");`

Answer (score 4):

It could be due to the formatting and encoding that your reader is using, try using Scanner instead.

Answer (score 2):

Java certainly is not doing that, it might be [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded file. Can you upload the file or a small part of it somewhere?